# Inventory list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access, microsoft-office-2013

I'm posting this as a new question, because the first one I posted wasn't very clear.

I'm making an inventory list in Excel, combined with a giveaway/borrow list. There are 3 spreadsheets containing items, the other 2 are the giveaway/borrow lists.

This is what one of the spreadsheets looks like (a mockup of it):

[image]

And this is the borrow list:

[image]

To clarify: from/to/back on are dates.

I want to do the following - When someone comes to the office to borrow an item, I want to write it in the borrow list, and have Excel automatically deduct that item from its quantity on the items list. I also want to add a popup window that tells me when there is no more of a certain item.

I read a couple of related questions but none of them contained such functions. Is this possible in Excel, or do I need Access? Is VBA any good, too?

So far, I have tried grouping elements in Excel and I'm currently trying to come up with an appropriate ID system. I also tried creating realtions between the tables in Access, but as I'm far from familiar with it, it hasn't really worked. In Excel, I tried using the IF() function, but I couldn't make it adjust/change the quantity value.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You could probably do this with formulas

Comment: 1) You need a unique key field to match items between sheets.  In the first table, that might be "Model"; in the second table, maybe "Inventory ID"?  You need matching contents between sheets.  2) On the Items list, you might want two quantity columns.  One for the total number you own, the other for what's left in stock considering the amounts in the Borrowed list.  You can use SUMIF to add up the number borrowed by item.  The on-hand quantity would be the total number minus the SUMIF.  3) Without getting fancy, you can use an adjacent column to show either blank or a warning if on-hand=zero.